# Programmer used my email address to send trojans - what to do?

Tags: email, blacklist, trojan

I forwarded my cPanel password to a programmer who was suppose to work on the website. Unfortunately he abuse my trust to create a new email account which he used after to send trojans. The hosting service caught it after aprox. 15.000 email were send and blocked the account. I deleted that account but I'm worried to get some kind of blacklisted for any email address with that `@example.com` ending or even worst the whole website `example.com`.

It there something I need to do to be able to prevent that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check to see if your server's IP address and host name have been added to blacklists by entering them in the blacklist tool here: http://mxtoolbox.com/NetworkTools.aspx

If you have been added to any blacklists, you can go to the website for that blacklist and follow their instructions for having your server removed.

Comment: Tanks a lot for your answer the link was very helpfull!